# When editing "Sites" list in the app, add a tab for my associated accounts

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, communities-list

In the iOS app for Stack Exchange, note the menu icon at bottom of short list of Stack Exchange accounts icons. That menu icon presents a dialog listing *all* Stack Exchange sites:

[image]

Can we please have a tab listing only the Stack Exchanges sites on which I have account i.e. the ones I've joined?

I want a quick way to jump to my less frequently visited Stack Exchanges.